# How to get client name and version using btdht

Tags: python, bittorrent

I'm using example code and it's working perfect, but this code only showing peer IP and port. All I want do is get peer client name and version for example Transmission 4.0 or something like this. There is some docs about it, but I don't know how to use it.

https://btdht.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package/btdht.krcp.html

I tried chatgpt, but code is kinda nonsense and not works.

```
>>> import btdht
>>> import binascii
>>> dht = btdht.DHT()
>>> dht.start()  # now wait at least 15s for the dht to boostrap
init socket for 4c323257aa6c4c5c6ccae118db93ccce5bb05d92
Bootstraping
>>> dht.get_peers(binascii.a2b_hex("0403fb4728bd788fbcb67e87d6feb241ef38c75a"))
[
    ('81.171.107.75', 17744),
    ('94.242.250.86', 3813),
    ('88.175.164.228', 32428),
    ('82.224.107.213', 61667),
    ('85.56.118.178', 6881),
    ('78.196.28.4', 38379),
    ('82.251.140.70', 32529),
    ('78.198.108.3', 10088),
    ('78.235.153.136', 10619),
    ('88.189.113.32', 33192),
    ('81.57.9.183', 5514),
    ('82.251.17.155', 14721),
    ('88.168.207.178', 31466),
    ('82.238.89.236', 32970),
    ('78.226.209.88', 2881),
    ('5.164.219.48', 6881),
    ('78.225.252.39', 31002)
]
```

Comment: note that "I tried chatgpt" does not really add context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some DHT implementations send a `v` field in the top level dictionary of some messages, indicating their version. Others don't and you'll have to establish a bittorrent connection instead to get the version from their [peer ID](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0020.html) or the [extended handshake](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0010.html)